# Combinatorial proof for multinomial identity

Tags: combinatorics

I have been wondering around in how to prove the multinomial identity:

$$
\binom{n}{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k} = \binom{n-1}{r_1-1,r_2,\dots,r_k} +  \binom{n-1}{r_1,r_2-1,\dots,r_k} + \dots +\binom{n-1}{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k-1},
$$

with $n=r_1+r_2+\dots+r_k$. The left part is easy, it's just how many $n$ letter words we can form if we have have $r_1$ letters of one type, $r_2$ letters of another type, etc.

The right part should be something similar, but I don't see how to connect both things.

Comment: At least one of the $r_i$ must be greater than 0. After all $n=r_1+\cdots+r_k$. So think about setting aside a single ball of type $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $r_i$ letters of type $i$, as you say for the left side.  Now consider the word formed, in a different way:  The *first* letter is of type $f$.  (We will have to sum over the possibilities for type $f$ later.)

The remainder of the word is a word formed from $n-1$ letters with counts
$\{ r_1, r_2, \ldots ,r_{f-1}, r_f-1, r_{f+1} \ldots r_k\}$.  So  we have $k$ components, each of which is iteself the appropriate multinomial coefficient. And that is your right hand side.

Comment: Actually could be any position in the $n$-letter word, right?

Comment: True, any fixed position.  But since we don't know how big $n$ is, we are only sure that there is a fisrt position and a last position.